# How to convert COMP field to decimal?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am working on a project which deals with conversion of COMP fields of COBOL to decimal, in SQL Server Integration Service (SSIS).

I am able to convert COMP-3 fields (Hexa-decimal representation) using the DLL provided by microsoft, called UnpackDecimal.dll.

But I am unable to convert the COMP field (binary representation) using the same DLL.

So please help me on this as i am in great need of it.

If some one could give me a DLL which can convert both COMP-3 and COMP, i would be very grateful to you.

Thanks,
Krishna Kumar

Comment: You say "I am unable to convert the COMP field", what error do you get or problem are you having? Some more information might help someone solve your problem.

Comment: Can you post an explanation highlighting the differences between COMP and COMP-3 encoding to a layman?

Comment: @littlegreen,  COMP stores its data in the binary format. COMP-3 stores the data in hexa-decimal format.

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't turn up any results on COMP conversion in SSIS, and nobody here has answered anything, so I think you are out of luck.

However, the [UnpackDecimal](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=0e4bba52-cc52-4d89-8590-cda297ff7fbd&displaylang=en) package description seems to be a distribution **with source code**. There are even some open todo-items "Left as exercise to the student" - seemingly this is part of some online Microsoft course to teach people how to develop their own SSIS packages.

So why don't you take up Microsoft's challenge and adapt this package to handle the COMP format as well? :) Afterwards, you can post it on the net so other people can use it too.

Comment: I'm currently busy in doing that. I hope i'll post a DLL which can handle both COMP and COMP-3 fields, here and over the net, with in a week.